# Can I run VScode on chromebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, dpkg, chromebook

I'm using Chromebook(asusu c101pa).

How I get VScode without [Community builds of

Visual Studio Code][1](https://code.headmelted.com/#chromeos-install-scripts)?

I've to try community builds of vscode, couldn't run. And, I'd like to use on linux.

I've downloaded deb file of vs code. But couldn't work. Error code sys

*An error occurred during installation of your Linux aaplication*

So, I do install Linux command(terminal), that too.

**myname@penguin:~$ sudo dpkg -i code_1.29.1-1542309157_amd64.deb**

dpkg:error processing archive code_1.29.1-1542309157_amd64.deb
(--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
rrors were encountered while processing:
 code_1.29.1-1542309157_amd64.deb

code_1.29.1-1542309157_amd64.deb is vscode file.

How I fix this problem?

Comment: "Chromebook" is not sufficient-there are multiple architectures etc.

Comment: Than you for teaching that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run VScode on a Chromebook! First, you need to enable Linux in settings. Next, you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Then, run command `sudo apt-get install -y gnome-keyring`. After that, run command `dpkg --print-architecture`. Remember this! Then, navigate out to `https://code.visualstudio.com/download` and based on what it says, download x64 or Arm64 respectively. Lastly, open files. There should be a file ending in `.deb`. Double-click this. That should download VScode!!